# Book Identification -- young adult novel witch

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read a chapter book (a novel) in 1975 or 1976, when I was 12. So I think it was possibly a novel geared to young adults. It was about a girl who either was a witch or became one during the story, and her name was Ariadne. She *may* have had red hair, but I'm not sure. It was definitely not about a Greek goddess, which is all I find when I search the internet; it had a contemporary setting. The cover, I think, was mostly black in my paperback version. No idea about when it was published, but as I said, I read it in the mid 70s. Does anyone know this book? I was quite taken with it.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly [The Active-Enzyme, Lemon-Freshened Junior High School Witch](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1440931.The_Active_Enzyme_Lemon_Freshened_Junior_High_School_Witch) (1973). According to a review:

> Alison is just getting over the measles, and while grounded one day she finds a book about witchcraft. She tries to follow it using common household items (a hair scrunchy can do for a garter in a pinch) and finds an isolated garret to practice her spells. Alison-now Ariadne Atropos Arachne-is all set on her idiosyncratic path to be a witch. Of course, witchcraft manuals really don't deal with nosy little sisters, so little Jeanne-now Jezebel-joins in.